# meteor iterate through array

Tags: mongodb, meteor

here is my collection

```
Ques_Coll.insert({question: quest,owner:u_name,comments:[]});
```

After user enters comment, collection will be updated like this

```
Ques_Coll.update({_id:this._id},{$push:{comments:{uname:"xxx",cmt_text:"xxx"}}});
```

Until this working fine

Now, i want to iterate through all the comments and want to display them

how to do it?

this is how i tried and not working

```
{{#each all_comments.comments}}
<li>{{uname}}</li>
<li>{{cmt_text}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

this is my template //i think my problem lies in this returning value

```
all_comments:function()
{
    return Ques_Coll.find( {_id:this._id},{fields: {'comments': 1}})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findOne` instead:

```
Ques_Coll.findOne( {_id:this._id},{fields: {'comments': 1}})
```

You use `find` when you're searching for more than one question to match the criteria. But since you're looking for one (the one with the comments), you use findOne instead.

Comment: `{{#each}} only accepts arrays, cursors, or falsey values. You passed: [object Object]` showing this error

Comment: if we use above `findOne` command how to iterate through the comments array

Comment: Just as you are doing currently because your comments are stored in the questions document in `comments`.